# Embed color profile sRGB in JPEG created from cocoa mac app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I use the following code in my cocoa mac app to create a JPEG. How can I also embed srgb color profile in the created JPEG?

```
NSImage* savedImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(600, 600)];
[savedImage lockFocus];
//draw here 
[savedImage unlockFocus];

NSBitmapImageRep* savedImageBitmapRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:[savedImage TIFFRepresentationUsingCompression:NSTIFFCompressionNone factor:1.0]];

NSDictionary* properties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality,
                            nil];

NSMutableData* imageData = [NSMutableData data];
CGImageDestinationRef imageDest =  CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((CFMutableDataRef) imageData, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, NULL);
CGImageDestinationAddImage(imageDest, [savedImageBitmapRep CGImage], (CFDictionaryRef) properties);
CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDest);

// Do something with imageData
if (![imageData writeToFile:[@"~/Desktop/test.jpg" stringByExpandingTildeInPath] atomically:NO])
    NSLog(@"Failed to write imageData");
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea how to do this with these high level APIs. I have done it by adding the needed IFDs to the JPEG data myself.

Comment: Unrelated, but do you have any links to documentation regarding on how to inject color profile info into a jpg, let's say, if you have the byte array of the image?